# Javascript Scope Issues for inner-function

Tags: javascript, firefox

Pretty sure this has been asked already, but I don't know what to search for. Anyway,

```
var livemarks = [];

var livemarkIds = PlacesUtils.annotations.getItemsWithAnnotation("livemark/feedURI", {});

for (var i = 0; i < livemarkIds.length; i++){

    PlacesUtils.livemarks.getLivemark( {id : livemarkIds[i]}, function(result, livemark){

        if (result == Components.results.NS_OK){
            livemarks.push(livemark);
        }

    });

}

alert(livemarks.length);
```

I am trying to play a bit with a Firefox addon that's no longer maintained by its creator, just to learn a bit. I recently got an error saying getFeedURI is going to be deprecated and I want to change his old function.

**EDIT:**

**From a function defined in a function (inner function), I am unable to access a var defined in the parent. Why?
E.g. I cannot access var livemarks from inside getLivemark(), or other similar internal functions.**

I was checking (scroll down completely): [this](https://github.com/cfinke/RSS-Ticker/blob/master/rss-ticker/chrome/content/ticker.object.js) and his code works fine. So what's wrong with my code? I just wanted to avoid the recursion, if possible.

Comment: Have you checked that `livemarks.push(livemark);` is being executed? With a console.log or a debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the `PlacesUtils.livemarks.getLivemark` function does its work *asynchronously*, so your callback is called *after* you alert the `length`. Put your alert *inside* the callback and you should see the correct length (eventually). Here's one way:

```
var expecting = livemarkIds.length;
for (var i = 0; i < livemarkIds.length; i++){

    PlacesUtils.livemarks.getLivemark( {id : livemarkIds[i]}, function(result, livemark){

        if (result == Components.results.NS_OK){
            livemarks.push(livemark);

            // ***New stuff***
            if (livemarks.length === expecting) {
                // Now you have them all, now you can do the next thing
                doSomethingWithTheLiveMarks(livemarks);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Note that there I put `livemarkIds.length` into `expecting`, just in case you do other things with `livemarkIds` while the function is running. If you aren't, you can just use that directly.

---

Re your comment below:

> However, the system works like this: I get the livemarks in an array. This code is in a class (and method) actually, so another class initializes this one and will call the function getFeeds(), which will return that array of livemarks.

If `PlacesUtils.livemarks.getLivemark` is asynchronous, it's *impossible* for `getFeeds` to return the array *as a return value*. E.g., it *cannot* be used like this:

```
a = b;
c = 42;
feeds = getFeeds(feedIds);
if (feeds.length === 0) {
    // Do something
}
else {
    // Do something else
}
```

The good news is it's really easy to fix: Have `getFeeds` accept a callback function that it calls when it has the feeds. The code above changes to look like this:

```
a = b;
c = 42;
feeds = getFeeds(feedIds, function(feeds) {
    if (feeds.length === 0) {
        // Do something
    }
    else {
        // Do something else
    }
});
```

As you can see, it's a pretty straightforward change. Assuming the loop above is *all* of `getFeeds`, then `getFeeds` ends up looking something like this:

```
function getFeeds(livemarkIds, callback) {

    var livemarks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < livemarkIds.length; i++){

        PlacesUtils.livemarks.getLivemark( {id : livemarkIds[i]}, function(result, livemark){

            if (result == Components.results.NS_OK){
                livemarks.push(livemark);

                if (livemarks.length === livemarkIds.length) {
                    // Done, trigger the callback
                    callback(livemarks);
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

And the pattern continues: If the code calling `getFeeds` is being called by something else that's expecting a return value from the async stuff, instead of returning that value, you have *that* code accept a callback, and call the callback from the `getFeeds` callback. And so on.

Once you get used to it, it's very easy to do. Getting used to it can be tricky. :-)

Comment: I need the retrieved livemarks, that I'm pushing into an array from outside this function. How do I get it out then, if I get length = 0 while reading from outer?

Comment: @Inf.S: You put the code that needs to use the IDs in a function you call from the callback, where I've said above `You have them all, now you can do the next thing` I've added a function call to the above to demonstrate.

Comment: @Inf.S: ...and I've added a more conceptual example.

Comment: I understand. However, the system works like this: I get the livemarks in an array. This code is in a class (and method) actually, so another class initializes this one and will call the function getFeeds(), which will return that array of livemarks. But even in the doYetAnotherThing(), I am unable to access an external var array, which is being returned empty. So the problem still remains: how do I access that outer var array?

Comment: @Inf.S: You're going to have to change `getFeeds` to accept a callback. If `PlacesUtils.livemarks.getLivemark` is asynchronous, it's *impossible* for `getFeeds` to return the array as a return value. So instead, you make `getFeeds` accept a callback, and then call the callback when you have them. This is standard asynchronous programming.

Comment: @Inf.S: I've updated the answer with some example code for `getFeeds` and an explanation of how you'd use it.

Comment: I have another class that heavily depends on this getFeeds() method. For e.g. methods like getFeedsCount: function() {return this.feed.getFeeds().length;} and isValid : function() {return (this.getFeedsCount() > 0 && this.index <= this.getFeedItemsLimit() && this.feed.items[this.index] !== undefined); How do I modify all that to deal with asynchronous calls? I'm kind of lost here, especially with respect to the length calls.

Comment: @Inf.S: It all comes down to moving the code that relies on the return value to rely on a callback instead. See the example in the answer, where all of the code that *was* working with the `getFeeds` return value works instead inside the callback.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it working. Actually, I created a sort of "after-load" method which I passed as callback to my getFeeds. So after getting feeds, it called the after-load and it had access to the feeds. I guess that's alright. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Inf.S: Excellent! Glad that helped, and the solution sounds good.